# Layout changes after aborting delete operation of uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a customer uitableviewcell with an image that is aligned to the right of the cell. When I swipe left to delete, and then abort, the image shows up even more to the right then before. Look at the attached image.

[image: Layout]

It looks like the cell is in some sort of edit mode, but I am not sure.

If I try the same approach on the cell below, it shows up in the same way as before (incorrect), but the cell that was previously shown incorrect goes back to normal.

So only one cell at a time...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

/Henrik

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Comment: unfortunately not...

Comment: I am stuck on the same issue. Did you find some workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I was able to solve it by setting the cell's accessoryView explicitly:

```
-(void) awakeFromNib
{
   self.accessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I analyzed the size of the content view before and after aborting the delete operation.

Initial frame dimensions of the cells.contentView:

```
cell.contentView: Origin: (0.000000, 0.000000), size: (568.000000,44.000000)
```

After aborting the delete operation:

```
cell.contentView: Origin: (0.000000, 0.000000), size: (320.000000,43.500000)
```

Currently I do not have a solution yet but I am investigating it further.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this issue dissapeared when I built my app using xcode 7 and running it on ios9. However, I Think that the main reason was just xcode 7.

Please try it out...

/Henrik